# how to update ko.observable text on click event?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This should be simple but certainly I'm getting it wrong.

How to update ko.observable text on the click event?
I could do this using "afterkeydown" or "keypress" but not in case click event.http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

```
<span data-bind="text: Count"></span>
<button data-bind="click: update">Update</button>

 function MyViewModel() {
     var self = this;

     self.Count = ko.observable("0");

     self.update = function() {
         self.Count = ko.observable("1");
     }
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EBsj5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change it like a function.

```
self.update = function() {
    self.Count("1");
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EBsj5/1/**

> Any basic tutorial will explain this to you, so I recommend watching a few.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing something basic as I'm novice.

Answer (score 2):

When you are setting the value of a Knockout observable, you need to use parans like a function and pass in the new value.

```
<span data-bind="text: Count"></span>
<button data-bind="click: update">Update</button>

 function MyViewModel() {
     var self = this;

     self.Count = ko.observable("0");

     self.update = function() {
         self.Count("1");
     }
 }
```

This will update the observable to "1" in this case.  You don't need to call ko.observable() again because you have already created the observable, you are simply trying to 'set' the value with the setter function.

Comment: Not a biggie, but as Pinocchio stated you should read some of the tutorials on Knockout as they are very helpful.  I only answered in hopes that if anyone in the future stumbles on this answer they have a better quick synopsis on why they need to use the parans, as it is probably the biggest Knockout related question that reoccurs on SO.com.  Actually if Pinocchio just edits his answer to include why the parans is necessary (to be a setter function) and why the second ko.observable isn't needed I will just delete this answer, as it isn't needed.

Comment: you are right that's why given +1. please don't delete your answer.